# Filter df when values matches part of a string in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` and I want to keep (so `filter`) all rows where the URL saved in the `location` column contains a pre-determined string, e.g. 'google.com'.

I have tried:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
df.filter(sf.col('location').contains('google.com')).show(5)
```

But this throws:

```
TypeError: _TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable'
```

How do I go around and filter my df properly?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

### Spark 2.2 onwards

> ```
> df.filter(df.location.contains('google.com'))
> ```
>
> [Spark 2.2 documentation link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)

---

### Spark 2.1 and before

> You can use **plain SQL** in `filter`
>
> ```
> df.filter("location like '%google.com%'")
> ```
>
> or **with DataFrame column methods**
>
> ```
> df.filter(df.location.like('%google.com%'))
> ```
>
> [Spark 2.1 documentation link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?fireglass_rsn=true#pyspark.sql.Column.contains)

Comment: Hi Srinivas, what if we had to check for two words, let's say `google.com` and `amazon.com` using `like`? How can we do so?

Comment: @cph_bon: There are many ways to do it. **SQL** `df.filter("location like '%google.com%' AND location like '%amazon.com%'")` or **DataFrame** `df.filter("location like '%google.com%'").filter("location like '%amazon.com%'")`

Comment: @mrsrinivas, what is we want to search "like 'ID' " in all columns. For instance,  daframe to have all columns that include word "ID"

Comment: For multiple substrings use rlike with a join like so: `df.filter(F.col("yourcol").rlike('|'.join(substrings)))` where substrings is a list of substrings like `substrings = ['google.com','amazon.com']`

Answer (score 23):

[`pyspark.sql.Column.contains()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.contains) is only available in pyspark version 2.2 and above.

```
df.where(df.location.contains('google.com'))
```

Comment: how to give more than one string in `.contains()`

Answer (score 8):

When filtering a DataFrame with string values, I find that the `pyspark.sql.functions` `lower` and `upper` come in handy, if your data could have column entries like "foo" and "Foo":

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sql_fun
result = source_df.filter(sql_fun.lower(source_df.col_name).contains("foo"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following expression, which helps you search for multiple strings at the same time:

```html
df.filter(""" location rlike 'google.com|amazon.com|github.com' """)
```