# How to efficiently check if a list of words is contained in a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

Using PySpark dataframes I'm trying to do the following as efficiently as possible. I have a dataframe with a column which contains text and a list of words I want to filter rows by. So:

Dataframe would look like this

```
df:
col1    col2   col_with_text
a       b      foo is tasty
12      34     blah blahhh
yeh     0      bar of yums
```

The list will be `list = [foo,bar]`
And thus result will be:

```
result:
col1    col2   col_with_text
a       b      foo
yeh     0      bar
```

Afterwards not only identical string matching will be done but also tested for similarity by using SequenceMatcher or so. This is what I already tried:

```
def check_keywords(x):
   words_list = ['foo','bar']

   for word in x
       if word == words_list[0] or word == words_list[1]:
           return x

result = df.map(lambda x: check_keywords(x)).collect()
```

Unfortunately I was unsuccesfull, could someone help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter df when values matches part of a string in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889974/filter-df-when-values-matches-part-of-a-string-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should consider using pyspark sql module functions instead of writing a `UDF`, there are several `regexp` based functions:

First let's start with a more complete sample data frame:

```py
df = sc.parallelize([["a","b","foo is tasty"],["12","34","blah blahhh"],["yeh","0","bar of yums"], 
                     ['haha', '1', 'foobar none'], ['hehe', '2', 'something bar else']])\
    .toDF(["col1","col2","col_with_text"])
```

If you want to filter lines based on whether they contain one of the words in `words_list`, you can use `rlike`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
words_list = ['foo','bar']
df.filter(psf.col('col_with_text').rlike('(^|\s)(' + '|'.join(words_list) + ')(\s|$)')).show()

    +----+----+------------------+
    |col1|col2|     col_with_text|
    +----+----+------------------+
    |   a|   b|      foo is tasty|
    | yeh|   0|       bar of yums|
    |hehe|   2|something bar else|
    +----+----+------------------+
```

If you want to extract the strings matching the regular expression, you can use `regexp_extract`:

```py
df.withColumn(
        'extracted_word', 
        psf.regexp_extract('col_with_text', '(?=^|\s)(' + '|'.join(words_list) + ')(?=\s|$)', 0))\
    .show()

    +----+----+------------------+--------------+
    |col1|col2|     col_with_text|extracted_word|
    +----+----+------------------+--------------+
    |   a|   b|      foo is tasty|           foo|
    |  12|  34|       blah blahhh|              |
    | yeh|   0|       bar of yums|           bar|
    |haha|   1|       foobar none|              |
    |hehe|   2|something bar else|              |
    +----+----+------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Hi, why are you using lookaheads in your regexps?

Answer (score 0):

Well I have tried this and if you change the word list.

`words_list = ['foo', 'is', 'bar']`

The result remains the same and it doesn't show the other words.

`+----+----+------------------+--------------+
    |col1|col2|     col_with_text|extracted_word|
    +----+----+------------------+--------------+
    |   a|   b|      foo is tasty|           foo|
    |  12|  34|       blah blahhh|              |
    | yeh|   0|       bar of yums|           bar|
    |haha|   1|       foobar none|              |
    |hehe|   2|something bar else|              |
    +----+----+------------------+--------------+`