# pyspark string match multiple exact words regular expression efficient way

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

Have a pyspark dataframe with one column `title` is  all string. Need to find all the rows which contain any of the  following list of words `['Cars','Car','Vehicle','Vehicles']`.
Need to filter to find only rows which contain word only from this list.
One way to do this like:

```
filter_1 = "title like '%{}' or title like '%{}' or title like '%{}' or title like '%{}'"\
    .format('Car','Cars','Vehicle','Vehicles')
    
df1 = df.filter(filter_1).select('id','title')
```

This is not a neat way to write.
Tried use regular expression:

```
df2 = df.where('title rlike "\bCars?\b|\bVehicles?\b"').select('id','title')
```

Only need to match exact word like 'Car' not 'sCar' or 'Carry'.
but df2 is empty.

Also tried [How to efficiently check if a list of words is contained in a Spark Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869922/how-to-efficiently-check-if-a-list-of-words-is-contained-in-a-spark-dataframe) there are still some extra strings like 'sCar' or 'Carry'.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use where to filter the df. To do that, join search words with `|`

```
s='|'.join(["(" + c +")" for c in l])
df.where(df['title'].rlike(s)).show()
```

Comment: How about only match car , not something like carry or scar?