# How to select a datum that contains a space?

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In the column "grape" there are data composed of two names, for example "chenin blanc"
How do I indicate that there is a space in those names?

This was my attempt

```
df_04 = vinos_df.select(countDistinct("name")).
df_041= df_04.filter(df_04.grape.like("% %")).show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter df when values matches part of a string in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889974/filter-df-when-values-matches-part-of-a-string-in-pyspark)

Comment: It looks like your first statement it wrong. You don't select the 'grape' column.